# Trigger to HCATALOG

Tags: python, hive, hcatalog

Can I add a trigger to HCATALOG to track any changes to HIVE tables?  I want to notify an audience about the HIVE table changes. If adding triggers is not possible, what are the other approaches?

Comment: Do you have access to the hive metastore?

Comment: Yes. I have access to Metastore

Comment: In hive metastore, there is a table called TBLS which you can query. I will post a SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the Hive metastore as below

Example Query

```
SELECT d.*, t.* 
  FROM hive.TBLS t
  JOIN hive.DBS d
    ON t.DB_ID = d.DB_ID
 WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN unix_timestamp('01-Dec-15  10.00.00', 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss')
                         AND unix_timestamp('07-Dec-15  10.00.00', 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss');
```

This query gives you all tables created between 1st Dec 10AM to 7th Dec 10AM.

SELECT the columns you are interested in.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is Great! Thanks Ramesh. I think tables like hive.SDS and hive.COLUMNS_V2 also must be used to get Column names and types. Now the question is if the Hive tables get changed(and assuming tables like COLUMNS_V2 get updated automatically), can a program(preferably Python) be triggered to update an audience? If yes,how?

Comment: You could  write a SQL to get the changes. For example SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBLS for create_date since last checked. If COUNT is greater than 1 your application could send an email or refresh a portal. That functionality has to be managed in your application. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I would say Yes. Thanks